# Rely on boolean value to access pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class called `MyClass` that contains a pointer to an object, like so:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : _blob(nullptr) {}
    ~MyClass() { free(); }

    void generate() {
        if(!_blob)
            _blob = new Blob;
    }

    void free() {
        if(_blob) {
            delete _blob;
            _blob = nullptr;
        }
    }

    Blob* getBlob() { return _blob; }

private:
    Blob *_blob;
};
```

The reason why it holds a pointer to a heap allocated object and doesn't contain it on the stack is because some `MyClass` instances don't allocate data for this object, therefore before accessing it I need to check if it's not a null pointer:

```
if(myClass->getBlob())
    myClass->getBlob()->doSomething();
```

Now I had this idea to store a bool variable called `_hasBlob` and then use it like this

```
if(myClass->hasBlob())
    myClass->getBlob()->doSomething();
```

Is this considered faster and legit? Or is it considered bad practice because I can see the danger potential of somehow ending up dereferencing a nullptr.

Comment: It's redundant and as such smelly. A  function for that is good, but make it test the pointer! No need to duplicate that information somewhere.

Comment: You should use a `std::unique_ptr` and avoid all of the mess at all. Just checking for the `nullptr` is OK and sufficient BTW.

Comment: This breaks the Law of Demeter AND Tell, Don't Ask. How about just having myClass->doSomething(), which does the null check and forwards the call on if not null?

Comment: @HappyCoder I edited my post. It will be defined like `bool hasBlob() const { return _hasBlob; }`

Comment: The thing is, I deal with functions that may query `getBlob()` (and potentially use it, if it's present) thousands of times per second. So I thought a bool check could be faster.

Comment: Maybe you could make a list of "blob-containing" MyClass instances, and use this list in the functions needing the blobs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's legit but redundant. It's not faster. Infact, while the check itself is as fast, maintaining the boolean in sync with the validity of the pointer is marginally slower. The worst thing about it is the maintenance burden of proving that the boolean is always in sync. Once it's implemented and proven correct though, it's just redundant and a waste of memory.

Comment: It's not just redundant, in this case adding a bool can double the sizeof the class.

Comment: @ChrisR. good point. I was assuming that the class is exmple of something larger. And there is no mention of how many instances there will be. If there will be many, then the size difference can significantly affect cache performance.

Comment: @ChrisR. Why is that? sizeof(bool) should be 1 byte and sizeof(ptr) is often 4 bytes.

Comment: @Pilpel `sizeof(bool)` is not necessarily 1, but even if it is, the alignment requirement of your class is at least the alignment requirement of the pointer which is most likely the size of the pointer and therefore the memory layout must be padded to be a multiple of the size of the pointer to satisfy the alignment requirement. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding

Answer (score 4):

In general, you would expect `MyClass::getBlob()` to always give you a valid object whenever you ask for it. So in general my suggestion would be to implement that method as follows:

```
Blob* getBlob() { 
  if(_blob == nullptr) { 
     _blob = new Blob; 
     // Or call private method generateBlob, if there is a lot of logic
  }

  return _blob; 
}
```

Alternatively, if default-constructed `Blob`s are small and you don't have thouasands of `MyClass` instances, you could just create the `Blob` object in the constructor and have `getBlob` return a reference, so you *never* have to check anything once you have a valid `MyClass` object.

If you want to avoid this automatic creation of `Blob` objects, you could add a `hasBlob` check, but instead of keeping a separate boolean, I would just implement it as

```
bool hasBlob() const { return _blob != nullptr; }
```

This function is almost certain to be inlined, doesn't cost you any extra storage, and it guarantees the correct result (for instance, it can never happen that you set `_hasBlob = true` and then fail to allocate a `Blob`). As you say, there is still a risk of dereferencing a null pointer, but as you have clearly documented (hopefully) that `getBlob` may return a null pointer if there is no Blob allocated for this instance, that risk is now with the caller and they should take care to check the result, as with any function returning a pointer. In fact, this solution is exactly equivalent to the code you already had, since `if(myObject->getBlob())` now does exactly the same check as `if(myObject->hasBlob())` would -- the only difference being that perhaps the latter is slightly more self-documenting.

Since you indicate in the comments that you are worried about the performance: I suspect that checking a pointer against `null` is fairly fast, but as usual, if you want to be sure, the usual advice of "Measure it!" holds. For example, you may find that because of the extra check in my first version of `getBlob` the compiler will not inline the function.

Comment: The OP said "some MyClass instances don't allocate data for this object"

Comment: This may cause many "identity" blob objects to be created. I don't want that

Comment: @Pilpel edited. Please let me know if the answer is now useful to you, otherwise I'll delete it.

Comment: the other comment answered exactly what I asked for. thanks though!